# Showing the students that belong to a trainer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to get all the students that belongs to a specific teacher in django-rest-framework. I have 2 classes that are in one to many relationship.Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Trainer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " "+self.surname


class Student(models.Model):
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " "+self.surname
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Trainer, Student


class TrainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trainer
        fields = ("__all__")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Trainer,Student
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import TrainerSerializer



class TrainerList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Trainer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrainerSerializer


class TrainerSingle(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Trainer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrainerSerializer

class TrainerCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Trainer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrainerSerializer
```

What I want is when I get the Trainer objects,I also want to see the students of a trainer (like when we do `trainerobj.query_set.all()` ) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `related_name` in your `Student` model's `trainer` field, and then you can query the students belongs to a trainer as, if you have `related_name` set to `students`.

```
trainer = Trainer.objects.prefetch_related('students').objects.get(pk=1)
trainer.students.all()
```

These will give you the related `students` of a `trainer`.

And if you don't want to set the `related_name` thing, then you can query the related students of a trainer as.

```
trainer = Trainer.objects.objects.get(pk=1)
trainer.student_set.all()
```

Comment: Then most likely I'd have to change the class based generic views.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to change the views. Just as @kishansilawat mentioned, add a `related_name` to the `trainer` to avoid using the auto-generated one:

```
trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students')
```

Then in your serializer, add the `StudentSerializer` and `students` field.

```
class StudentSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("__all__")

class TrainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Trainer
        fields = ("__all__")
```